# the usage of adding @property before an @abstractmethod function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, abc

In the design of the abstract base class, I can find the following scenarios. What are the design considerations of adding @property for a method in the abstract base class. When I implement the related function, e.g., `f1` here, are there any differences comparing to implementing `f1`, which does not have `@property` decorator?

```
@abstractmethod
def f(self)
     pass

@property
@abstractmethod
def f1(self)
    pass
```

Comment: Do you understand how the decorator works *normally*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be an abstract property. [From docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty):

> A subclass of the built-in `property()`, indicating an abstract property.
>
> This special case is deprecated, as the `property()` decorator is now correctly  identified as abstract when applied to an abstract method:
>
> ```py
> class C(ABC):
>     @property
>     @abstractmethod
>     def my_abstract_property(self):
>         ...
> ```

This would allow you to do something like this:

```
class CD(C):
    def my_abstract_property(self):
        return 1

cd = CD()
print(cd.my_abstract_property)
# Outputs 1
```

However, if you had only a `@abstractmethod` decorator in the first place, such as

```py
class C(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def my_abstract_property(self):
        ...
```

you would have to do

```
class CD(C):
    def my_abstract_property(self):
        return 1

cd = CD()
#                            vv
print(cd.my_abstract_property())
# Outputs 1
```